# Any restriction on number of record insertion in BigQuery?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

We are trying to insert estimate near to 0.1 million records in one go!However, That script is inserting all 0.1 mi records in MySql whereas the similar script is prematurely terminating after insertions of around 27K records in Big Query!

Also We didn't find any error during the termination of script from Big Query API.Please help us to know the reason,  If it BQ has set any limit on insertions or something else!

Comment: You can find all the information you need on streaming here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts

Answer (score 1):

Streaming insert works better if you make it in parallel. For large data use load jobs with files. Make sure you handle errors correctly, as from a batch of rows some can fail, and some can go through. You will need to deal with this issue when handling errors.

The following limits apply for streaming data into BigQuery.

- Maximum row size: 1 MB. Exceeding this value will cause invalid errors.
  HTTP request size limit: 10 MB. Exceeding this value will cause invalid errors.
- Maximum rows per second: 100,000 rows per second, per table. 1,000,000 rows per second, per project. Exceeding either amount will cause quotaExceeded errors.
- Maximum rows per request: There is no hard limit, but we recommend a maximum of 500 rows. Batching can increase performance and throughput to a point, but at the cost of per-request latency. Too few rows per request and the overhead of each request can make ingestion inefficient. Too many rows per request and the throughput may drop. We recommend using about 500 rows per request, but experimentation with representative data (schema and data sizes) will help you determine the ideal batch size.
- Maximum bytes per second: 100 MB per second, per table. Exceeding this amount will cause quotaExceeded errors.